# WSDL generated code not deserializing long in XML properly

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have been given a WSDL by one of our suppliers that contains the following:

```
<xsd:element name="RegistrationResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="DateTimeStamp" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
            <xsd:element name="EchoData" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
            <xsd:element name="TransactionTrace" type="xsd:long" nillable="true"/>
            <xsd:element name="ResponseCode" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
            <xsd:element name="ResponseMessage" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
            <xsd:element name="ClientAccNumber" type="xsd:long" nillable="true"/>
            <xsd:element name="BranchCode" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
            <xsd:element name="HIN" type="xsd:long" nillable="true"/>
            <xsd:element name="EasyPayRef" type="xsd:long" nillable="true"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

However sometimes the response I get back from them will not contain all the fields. For example in this instance:

```
 <soapenv:Body>
    <tpw:RegistrationResponse>
      <DateTimeStamp>
        2012-04-02T19:10:41.4430564Z
      </DateTimeStamp>
      <EchoData/>
      <TransactionTrace>
        5418721751027669946
      </TransactionTrace>
      <ResponseCode>
        25
      </ResponseCode>
      <ResponseMessage>
        Invalid Mobile Account Type
      </ResponseMessage>
      <ClientAccNumber/>
      <BranchCode/>
      <HIN>
        0
      </HIN>
      <EasyPayRef/>
    </tpw:RegistrationResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
```

Now the code generated by the code in Visual Studio when adding a service reference does not like the fact that the ClientAccNumber is blank. The generated code looks as follows:

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://tpwebservice.x.com", Order=5)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true)]
    public System.Nullable<long> ClientAccNumber;
```

I get an 'Input was not in the correct format' exception when it tries to deserialize the response received from the server. What I'm thinking is that it sees a blank string and tries to parse a long out of it, which obviously fails.  I tried to add minOccurs="0" to the wsdl which didn't help.

How do I fix the wsdl, or the generated code, to solve this problem? Or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the code to define the property as a string, and have a non-XML-serializable property with the actual `Nullable<long>` value that is converted to/from the string:

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://tpwebservice.x.com", Order=5)] 
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ClientAccNumber", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true)] 
public string ClientAccNumberStr; 

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute]
public System.Nullable<long> ClientAccNumber {
  get {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ClientAccNumberStr))
      return null;
    return long.Parse(ClientAccNumberStr);
  }
  set {
    if (!value.HasValue) {
      ClientAccNumberStr = null;
    } else {
      ClientAccNumberStr = value.Value.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But in order to add the extra attribute I need to edit the generated code, which becomes quite a nightmare as everytime the WSDL is regenerated the changes are lost.

Comment: You have a WSDL that does not match the XML you are getting - you'll have either to fix the WSDL each time it is modified or fix the code, I don't see a way around that.

Comment: Or ask the supplier to send a nil instead of an empty element? Or can you somehow preprocess their XML and correct it is necessary ?

Comment: I got them to send a "<ClientAccNumber xsi:nil="true"></ClientAccNumber>" however that still breaks the deserialization. Nillable is specified in the WSDL. Why is it still breaking?

Comment: Works for me, with a simple test class. Which error are you getting?